# Add configuration parameters - spark & Kafka : acks and compression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to add some parameters to my application spark & Kafka for writing a Dataframe into topic kafka.

I havn't found acks and compression.codec in spark-kafka documentation

````
   .write
   .format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", Config.KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM)
   .option("kafka.security.protocol", Config.KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL)
   .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", KAFKA_JAAS_CONFIG)
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP)
   .option("fetchOffset.numRetries", 6)
   .option("acks","all")
   .option("compression.codec","lz4")
   .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 120000)
   .option("topic", topic)
   .save()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use this particular property to define your serializer :
default.value.serde

Comment: What about the message key? I've not seen this property mentioned in the Spark docs

Answer (score 0):

For serializers, make a case class or otherwise one to three column Dataframe that just holds `Array[Byte]` fields for `key` and `value` (String will also work). Then `topic` String field. If you only need the Kafka value, then you only need one column Dataframe

You'll need to map over your current data to serialize it all before writing to Kafka.

Then, the documentation does say any other producer property is just prefixed with `kafka.`

More information here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka

For SASL properties, I think you need to use `spark.executor.options` and pass key tabs or jaas files with `--files` during submit, though

Comment: I want add Acks property via  .option("","")

Comment: `kafka.acks` should be it, as per the documentation